# How to Query function for multiple counts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet being used as a property index which has a list of property with its summary details such as location, type, number of bedrooms etc.

I'm trying to count the number of how many 1 bedroom, 2 bedroom, 3 bedroom properties etc there are in each location.

However, I'm not sure how to do multiple counts, for example where column W = 1 and (next column) where W = 2 etc

```
=QUERY(Property_Location_Type,"select T, count(T) where W='1' Group by T",1)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try something alike:

formula in cell Y1 here:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({T2:T,TO_TEXT(IF(W2:W>2,">2",W2:W))&{"",""}},"Select Col1, Count(Col2) Where Col1!='' group by Col1 PIVOT Col3 label Col1 'Town/City'"))`

-

[image]

Comment: Works as intended. Thanks